# The new UI changes lack in user experience

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface, activity-tab

I don’t like the new UI updates. This may be good if viewed from small-screen devices, but for a desktop user, it is awful. Even though there are discussions about the UI changes, this is about the changes that came into action from the last day.

### Tags Section

[image: The tags section has a lot of blank space in the middle.]

Here is the tags section. In the previous version, the tags section was properly placed in a minimal space, but now it takes the whole view space.

### Question and Answer Section

[image: One screen contains the answer section and part of the question section.]

In the previous UI version, users could see both questions and answers tabs side by side, but now we have to scroll down to see the answers section.

### Reputation Section

[image: The reputation section has a bar graph at the top, however the width of the bars is maximally expanded, leaving no space between the bars. The bar graph is also not labeled in either axis.]

This is the main reason that prompted me to write this report: that bar graph looks weird (at least on desktop). If I want see today's reputation status, I have to scroll all the way to the bottom, previously that was available at the top.

Considering all these the new UI Changes are disastrous!!

### Suggestion

Instead of putting these sections into a single column, make it multiple columns according to the content.

Comment: There's a main MSE post for the comments/bugs at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page

Comment: Yeah but also Profile page looks more different than Activity page now

Comment: Already reported: [Instead of useful features, layout update contained bobcat. Would not buy again.](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/372653/289905), Tags Section: [\[1\]](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/372619/289905), Reputation Section: [\[1\]](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/372603/289905), [\[2\]](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/372608/289905), [\[3\]](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/372664/289905), or just do a `Ctrl`+`F` across all three pages of answers and search for “density”, “space”, etc.